PyQt application issue by changing Windows display scale, or in different resolutions
When changing the display scaling in Windows 11 from 100% to 125% or 150%, the PyQt5 application and its elements (labels, buttons, text, tables, etc.) change size accordingly.
image
While setting the environment variable prevents these elements from resizing, it causes the entire application window to become very large, similar to a zooming effect.
 os.environ["QT_ENABLE_HIGHDPI_SCALING"] = "1"

How can I prevent this zooming effect and allow the application to be displayed at scaling levels other than 100% while maintaining the original size of its elements?
In an ideal scenario, I'd like the application to display at its native size (100% scaling) regardless of the system's overall scaling level. This means the application window would essentially ignore scaling adjustments above 100% and maintain its original appearance.
Code:
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow

# Disable high-DPI scaling by setting the environment variable
os.environ["QT_ENABLE_HIGHDPI_SCALING"] = "0"

# Create the application instance
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

# Set application attributes to ignore system scaling
app.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, False)
app.setAttribute(Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps, False)
app.setAttribute(Qt.AA_DisableHighDpiScaling, True)

# Manually set the device pixel ratio to 1.0
screen = QGuiApplication.primaryScreen()
screen.setProperty("devicePixelRatio", 1.0)

# Your main window code here
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 Application")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)
        label = QLabel("Hello, PyQt5!", self)
        label.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid black")
        label.move(50, 50)

# Create and show the main window
window = MainWindow()
window.show()

# Start the application's event loop
sys.exit(app.exec_())

Here is the difference in Windows scale 100% vs 150%
Scales

That seems a terrible objective. If the system is using scaling, is almost always for good reasons, including screen DPI or, even more importantly, visual impairment of the user. Forcibly showing a very small UI, completely disregarding user settings and necessities is wrong.

Another thing: if a property does not have a setter function, it generally means that the property is read only. Which is quite obvious for devicePixelRatio() of QScreen, since a program could not (nor should!) be able to do so.

@musicamante Thanks, I appreciate your points.  Excluding that scenario, what's the common approach for handling different screen scales? Do experts create multiple UIs? It seems inefficient. Perhaps there's another way – that's why I'm asking. My current approaches haven't worked well. Additionally, what if maintaining a consistent and unique visual style is a higher priority for us? If achievable, I can redesign based on the best practices we discover.

Qt is quite capable of properly scaling the ui as long as layout managers are used, considering proper ratios between widget requirements and font scaling.
